# Clustered column chart for year over year quarterly data, improper spacing(pivot table)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table

How can I group columns in Clustered column chart for year over year quarterly data(pivot table)? In the example, I wish to have 2016 and 2017 values for a particular month grouped together for proper comparison.  (I manually changed the column colours for 2017, for the time being)
[image: pivot table and chart]